# adicionar texto a uma textarea sem apagar o existente

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho uma textarea ( id='texto'), que o usuário digita o seu texto livremente (até ai tudo bem), no final ele clica em um botão que insere uma assinatura exemplo: "Digitado por fulano".

Quando ele insere esse novo texto o antigo é removido, eu gostaria de poder adicionar o novo texto sem remover o antigo. Alguém tem alguma dica/ajuda?

Comment: Pode colocar o código que está utlizando?

Comment: document.getElementById('texto').value;
-
Quando tento inserir o antigo texto sai, e  entra o novo :/

Comment: @Moreirasouza, poderia [edit] seu post e adicionar seu código todo, acredito que a solução seria so um operador de concatenação `+=` no lugar certo ;)

Comment: <textarea id="texto"> texto que tem que ficar tbm  </textarea> o problema é esse eu nao tenho ideia de como fazer, eu tento fazer assim. document.getElementById(texto).value+"frase que tbm ficara"; e nao da certo... perdao os erros estou pelo celular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usas `el.value = 'foo';` vais **apagar** o conteúdo existente e **subsituir** por `foo`.
Quando usas `el.value += 'foo';` vais **manter** o conteudo existente e **acrescentar* `foo`.

Usar `+=` é um atalho que na prática faz `el.value = el.value + 'foo';`

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var assinatura = '\n\nCumprimentos,\nSuper heroi.'

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.value += assinatura;
});
```

```css
button {
    display: block;
}
textarea {
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="texto" id="texto"></textarea>
<button type="button">Assinar</button>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbn7y4L7/

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, funcionou perfeitamente !!

O que me falta mesmo é prestar mais atenção aos detalhes, e  aprofundar mais a lógica, porque pelo que percebi era algo simples. 

addEventListener  ainda estou tentando entender um pouco, sempre esqueço como usa-lo. Agradeço a sua ajuda e aos demais.